# Netbeans + maven on Ubuntu

Tags: maven, plugins, netbeans

I have a properly set up Maven project, and my Netbeans on Windows recognizes it and can build it properly, but my Netbeans on Ubuntu wouldn't even see the project as a Netbeans project.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 16):

Maven support in Netbeans comes in the form of an official plugin. The version that ships with Ubuntu has almost no plugins installed. To resolve this, navigate to `Tools ▶ Plugins` and install the Maven plugin from there. After a restart of the IDE, all Maven projects should be recognized automatically.

If you don't see the list of plugins, make sure the repositories are enabled in the `Tools ▶ Plugins ▶ Settings` tab. Check at least  `Certified Plugins` and  `NetBeans Distribution`. Reload the catalog in the `Available Plugins` tab. Now you should see a list of all available plugins.

Comment: Actually, the Maven plugin is not in "Certified Plugins" but in "NetBeans Distribution". Anyway, thanks @t.heinz for that answer, it helped me a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Xubuntu when I downloaded netbeans with synaptic.

I have uninstalled the netbeans on synaptic et install the netbeans with all avalaible on netbeans website and it works fine (last column). I can now import maven project. Hope it helps you.

http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html